# Need some way to store functions in a list, and then call them

Tags: c++, list, function, stl

This list, has to hold functions, they might be from different namespaces and even methods of instanced classes.
This list will then be iterated and all the functions and methods called. It would be nice if they could contain arguments also.

I was thinking on using a std::vector, but I suspect that I am far from correct in that guess.

What approach do you recommend me? All help is welcome.

Comment: Could we have more specifics about these functions? (ie possible return types and parameters) Also, I think you meant "iterated" instead of "recursed".

Comment: a few years ago I'da said to use boost:function, but nowadays I dunno...

Comment: @Colin: Why not boost::function?

Comment: @quasiverse Yes you are right, I sometimes get confused when writing long english sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have all of your functions implement the [Command Pattern.](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/command.html)

Your list becomes a

```
std::list<Command>
```

As you iterate over the list, you invoke the Execute() method of each list item.

For example, say you have a simple Command interface called Commander:

```
class Commander
{
public:
    virtual        ~Commander;

    virtual void    Execute();//= 0;
};
```

And you have three objects that you want to put in your list: A Greyhound, a Gyrefalcon, and a Girlfriend. Wrap each in a Commander object that calls the object's function of interest. The Greyhound runs:

```
class RunGreyhound: public Commander
{
public:
    void            Execute()
                    {
                        mGreyhound->Run();
                    }
private:
    Greyhound*      mGreyhound;
};
```

The Gyrefalcon flies:

```
class RunGyrefalcon: public Commander
{
public:
    void            Execute()
                    {
                        mGyrefalcon->Fly( mGyrefalcon->Prey() );
                    }    
private:
    Gyrefalcon*      mGyrefalcon;
};
```

And the Girlfriend squawks:

```
class RunGirlfriend: public Commander
{
public:
    void            Execute()
                    {
                        mGirlfriend->Squawk( mGirlfriend->MyJunk(), mGirlfriend->Mytrun() );
                    }
private:
    Girlfriend*     mGirlfriend;
};
```

Stuff the Commander objects in your list. Now you can iterate over them and invoke each element's Execute() method:

```
std::list<Commander> cmdlist;

RunGreyhound dog;
cmdlist.push_back( dog );

RunGyrefalcon bird;
cmdlist.push_back( bird );

RunGirlfriend gurl;
cmdlist.push_back( gurl );

for ( std::list<Commander>::iterator rit = cmdlist.begin(); rit != cmdlist.end(); ++rit )
{
    rit->Execute();
}
```

Comment: I just cannot find any documentation about this. Can you please show me a minimal code for me to understand?

Comment: I expanded my answer with a (very) minimal example.

Answer (score 5):

You could use std::function and std::bind if your compiler already supports it.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

void x(int) {}
void y() {}
class Z {
public:
    void z() {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef std::function<void ()> VoidFunc;
    typedef std::vector<VoidFunc> FuncVector;
    FuncVector functions;

    functions.push_back(std::bind(&x, 1));
    functions.push_back(&y);
    Z z1;
    functions.push_back(std::bind(&Z::z, z1));

    for(FuncVector::iterator i = functions.begin(); i != functions.end(); i++) {
        (*i)();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an existing solution such as boost::function, you will need to create a base class that represents a function, and then derived classes that wrap various sources of functions.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using std::cout;
using std::list;

struct Function {
  virtual ~Function() { }
  virtual void operator()() = 0;
};

struct PlainFunction : Function {
  PlainFunction(void (*function_ptr_arg)()) : function_ptr(function_ptr_arg) { }
  virtual void operator()() { (*function_ptr)(); }
  void (*function_ptr)();
};

template <typename T> 
struct MethodFunction : Function {
  MethodFunction(T &obj_arg,void (T::*method_ptr_arg)())
    : obj(obj_arg), method_ptr(method_ptr_arg)
  {
  }
  virtual void operator()() { (obj.*method_ptr)(); }
  T &obj;
  void (T::*method_ptr)();
};

void f()
{
  cout << "Called f()\n";
}

struct A {
  void f() { cout << "Called A::f()\n"; }
};

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  list<Function *> functions;
  functions.push_back(new PlainFunction(f));
  A a;
  functions.push_back(new MethodFunction<A>(a,&A::f));
  list<Function *>::iterator i = functions.begin();
  for (;i!=functions.end();++i) {
    (*(*i))();
  }
  while (!functions.empty()) {
    Function *last_ptr = functions.back();
    functions.pop_back();
    delete last_ptr;
  }
}
```